# Logistic regression perfect fit but non-significant coefficients

Tags: logistic, p-value

I have a data set for customers with some columns like sign-up-date, address-added-date, credit-card-added-date and order-placed-date. Only a portion of signup customers added address, a portion of them added credit card information, and at the end most of them do not place orders. So most of the cells in this data set is NA. The goal is to predict whether a sign-up customer will place an order. I convert all the dates,except the sign-up-date into binary variable, to indicate whether a sign-up customer will add address or add credit card. I then use these two binary variable to fit the binary outcome of whether a customer has placed order. I use logistic regression, and have perfect fit. However, I have very high p-values. How do I interpret this result?
[image]

Comment: Why do you say that you have a prefect fit?  You parameter estimates all have very large standard errors.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I am new to logistic regression. The predicted values are all +/-26.56607, which are far off 0/1. But I used this for classification which perfectly match the binary result +26.56607 for 1 and -26.56607 for 0.

Comment: Can you show us the results of running `confint(fit.logistic)`?  (maybe you have to do `library(mass)` first).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have errors...need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
In addition: There were 38 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: what is the correlation between `mydata3[6]` and `mydata3[7]`?

Comment: I have a suspicion that you've included a predictor variable in your model that is perfectly correlated (or nearly so) with your outcome.  it's just a thought.  Run a cross tab of each of your predictors with your outcome to be sure.

Comment: @Michael Look at the residual deviance.

Comment: It looks to me like either multicollinearity or perfect separation about which there are many questions and answers here. What does `cor(as.matrix(mydata3[,c(11,6,7)]))` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you cross-tabulate mydata3[,11] and mydata3[,7]? The magnitude of the effect for mydata3[,6] is so small and in comparison mydata3[,7] appears very large. Could be an indication of deterministic relationship between data3[,11] and data3[,7] - In this case it does not make sense to run a logistic regression (Did you face some convergence issues?)